# C++ Question about memory pretty basic but this is confusing me

Tags: c++

Not really too c++ related I guess but say I have a signed int
int a =50;
This sets aside like 32 bits memory for this right it'll get some bit patternand a memory address, now my question is basically well we created this variable but the computer ITSELF doesn't know what the type is it just sees some bit pattern and memory address it doesn't know this is an int, but my question is how? Does the computer know that those 4 bytes are all connected to a? And also how does the computer not know the type? It set aside 4 bytes for one variable I get that that doesn't automatically make it an int but does the computer really know nothing? The value was 50 the number and that gets turned into binary and stored in the bit pattern how does the computer know nothing

Comment: The computer itself doesn't really know anything. The program knows because the compiler generated instructions that say to treat that memory as an `int`.

Comment: But those 4 bytes is it fair to say that technically the computer knows they belong to the variable a?

Comment: The deeper you delve into CPU architectures and the underbelly of C++ the more you'll realize that there are no basic memory questions. For example, that variable might not be in memory at all. And if it is in memory, there might not be any RAM backing it at any given point in time. Do you think that's air you're breathing now?

Comment: The computer knows that it has RAM memory, and a list of opcodes (generated for it by your C++ compiler) that it should execute, that tell it how to update the contents of that RAM in very precisely defined ways.  The CPU blindly executes the provided instructions and hopes for the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Type information is used by the compiler. It knows the size in bytes of each type and will create an executable that at runtime will correctly access memory for each variable.

Comment: Access, interpret, display, or what-have-you. The computer knows nothing. The program knows everything.

Comment: @user4581301 It's just a rock we tricked into thinking

Comment: That's a decent way of looking at it. My view is computers aren't smart. They're just stupid, really, really fast.

Comment: Hey, I've been using that line for over 30 years :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a compiled language and is not run directly by the computer. The computer itself runs machine code. Since machine code is all binary, we will often look at what is called assembly language. This language uses human readable symbols to represent the machine code but also corresponds to it on a line by line basis

When the compiler sees `int a = 50;` It might (depending on architecture and compiler)

```
mov r1 #50  // move the literal 50 into the register r1
```

Registers are placeholders in the CPU that the cpu can use to manipulate memory. In the above statement the compiler will remember that whenever it wants to translate a statement that uses a into machine code, it needs to fetch the value from r1

In the above case, the computer decided to map `a` to a register, it may well use memory instead.

The type itself is not translated into machine code, it is rather used as a hint as to what types of assembly operations subsequence c++ statements will be translated into. The CPU itself does not understand types. Size is used when loading and storing values from memory to registers. With a char type one 1 byte is read, with a short 2 and an int, typically 4.

When it comes to signedness, the cpu has different instructions for signed and unsigned comparisons.

Lastly float either have to simulated using integer maths or special floating point assembler instructions need to be used.

So once translated into assembler, there is no easy way to know what the original C++ code was.